# Pagination in DocumentDB

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Is it possible to limit and offset results in documentDB to achieve pagination using LIMIT and OFFSET doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM root LIMIT 10 //this fails
```

In mongo I can do this with function chaining like

```
.limit(10).offset(30).toArray()
```

Does documentDB support similar functionality? I am using Node

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently supported, but you iterate thorough the results using `{maxItemCount: N}` and `executeNext()`. Take a look at the tests [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/blob/master/source/test/test.js) for an example of how to do this, e.g., it("[nativeApi] validate queryIterator nextItem and hasMoreResults")

**EDIT:** DocumentDB now supports TOP in the grammar. Details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-paging-support-with-top-and-more-query-improvements/).